# Add link for CPT to another CPT on submit button

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 2 different CPT : Tournament and Team.

I have a submit button on the tournament template.

On submit the team register in tournament cpt ( with metaboxes or something else )

For instance, I manage the team A and want to register on tournament B
On tournament B there is a button called " register ".

The TeamName saved in BO in tournament CPT.

On frontend : Tournament A list => the TeamName register.

Please help me solve this.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I just wan to say that I can add a teamname manually in back office and display it on the front end but not the reverse

Comment: Sorry for late response,

Iam trying to call a plugin on the submit wich create new metabox on the same wodel I made it for create them in back office

Comment: What I meant was, please share some code and what you have tried to get this working so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

> class oArenaAddTeam {
>       public function __construct() {
>           add_action ('init', [$this, 'addTeamTournament']);
>       }
>
> ```
> function addTeamTournament()
> {
>     // add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'addTeamTournament');
>     // $post = get_post_type();
>
>     // echo 'you are here';
>      $author_id = get_current_user_id();
>
>     $args = array(
>         'author' => $author_id,
>         'post_type' => 'team',
>         'order' => -1
>     );
>
>     $user = get_posts($args);
>     // untill there i have the var dump ok with post author 
>     // var_dump($user);
>     // exit;
>     if (isset($_POST['register-team-tournament'])) 
>     {
>         echo 'there';
>         function init_metabox_tournament() 
>         {
>             add_meta_box('team_register_tournament', '', 'team_register_tournament', 'tournament', 'normal' );
>         }   
>
>         function team_tournament($post)
>         {
>             // var_dump($post);
>             // die;
>             $team_tournament = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_team_register_tournament', true);
>
>         }
>
>         add_action('save_post', 'save_metabox_tournament');
>
>         function save_metabox_tournament($post_id)
>         {
>             if (isset($_POST['register-team-tournament'])) 
>             {
>                 update_post_meta($post_id, '_team_register_tournament', $user->post_title);
>             }
>         }
>     } else {
>         echo 'wrong';
>     }
> } }
>
>
>
>
> <form action="add-team" method="post">
> <input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" name="register-team-tournament"">
> </form>
> ```

Thanks in advance :D